# How to add time of timeType to DateTimeType

Tags: php, symfony

I want to add variable of type TimeType to a variable of DateTimeType

I have triying this code :

```
$newDate = $dateAppointment->add($duration);
```

but i got this error

> Warning: DateTime::add() expects parameter 1 to be DateInterval,
>   object given

**Examples of data:**

```
$dateAppountment = 2019-03-21 10:15:00 
$duration : 00:15:00
```

Comment: `var_dump($duration)`, what is it exactly?

Comment: In input i have set 1 hours : 
object(DateTime)#1404 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "1970-01-01 01:00:00.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/Berlin" }

Comment: In database i got 01:00:00

Comment: You somehow need to transfom DateTime object to DateInterval object and pass this DateInterval object as argument to `add` method.

Comment: how do you fetch your duration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose there's some kind of transformer already exists in symfony, but I can't find it. So, here's a custom code how to convert time from `DateTime` to `DateInterval` and add it to another `\DateTime`:

```
$dateAppointment = (new \DateTime());

$dtDuration = (new \DateTime())->setTime(1, 15, 0);
$duration = $duration->format('\P\TH\Hi\Ms\S');

$newDate = $dateAppointment->add(new \DateInterval($duration));
```

Fiddle: https://3v4l.org/5lFlQ

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
$duration = '1970-01-01 01:00:00.000000';
$timeObject = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s.u', $duration, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$date = '2019-03-21 10:15:00';
$dateObject = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date);

$modify = '+' . $timeObject->format('U') . ' second';
echo $dateObject->modify($modify)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Just get the seconds from your duration object and add them to your date object. If you used `modify`, there are a lot of things you can do.